# How to list object's array properties by sorted?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

Each user has some professionals in array:

```
users  idxxx 
           -A
           -prof: name: x
                  name: y
       idyyy
           -B
           -prof: name :y
                  name :z
                  name :x
```

how to sort prof arrays lists by name order.
something like:

```
prof list: 
x (2)               
y (2)               
z (1)
```

Comment: The structure as it's presented in the question isn't valid. You can't have keys within the node with duplicate names - I mention that because even if they were different, it's not an array unless they were numbered sequentially. On that note, you can't order or sort a Firebase array. It's one 'thing' and the elements cannot be accessed individually. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should denormalize your data model, i.e. create a dedicated extra "proflist" node in your database where you will increment the number of the corresponding profession(s) when you create a new user.

Actually it corresponds to the way you have explained your problem.

Better use a transaction as detailed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Answer (score 1):

A better, alternative structure will alleviate the issue.

```
user_01
  -name: A
  -professors
     -YUik99j9s
         name: "prof name 0"
     -YJ89jk9sk
         name: "prof name 1"
```

then read in the node

```
ref = "user_01/professors"
```

and

```
orderBy:("name")
```

Note that the professor child keys (-YUik99j9s and -YJ89jk9sk) are created with push() or childByAutoId depending on platform.